# Get data from another URL - Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to get data from JSON which is returned from URL 
(http://localhost:8042/patients/)

I prepared Model in which I have all the same fields as on returned JSON.

I just wanted to get data and save it on my MongoDB, but firstly it will be okay if I can return the same JSON on my endpoint.

I tried it like below but it doesn't work.

```java
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/test")

public class PatientController {

    @GetMapping("/patient")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity patient()  {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8042/patients/123SomeId123";

        ResponseEntity<Patient> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Patient.class);


        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: ExceptionHandlingController [http-nio-9081-exec-1] unexpected error org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8042/patients/someID": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: It seems that the server that you are trying to access is not responding, you should check if the server is up and running and it is responding ok on that url. I am refering to the service listening in localhost:8042

Comment: Have you tried accessing URL directly ?

Comment: It works correctly. When I run it on postman it gives my json file.

Comment: Did you run your java app on a docker container? if yes, then `localhost` address could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, my backend run on docker container. So how should I replace address?

Comment: The route in your example is `/test/patient` but you are trying to access `/patients/someId`, why is that?

Comment: On localhost:8042 I have separate server from which I have to get some data

Comment: Have you tried to change the port of another server?

Comment: You mean change localhost:8042 for localhost with another port?

Comment: Just want to check whether two servers are on different ports. 
Also change localhost to 192.168.100.99 , this is docker default IP. 
This might work..!!

Comment: My backend (localhost:9081) and orthanc server (localhost:8042) are on different ports. Change as above doesnt work. Maybe I have something wrong in my endpoint? Any idea?

Comment: Share second API that you are calling in the post

Comment: Second API is built REST API for Orthanc server. I have installed Orthanc server on my PC and I have server on localhost:8042. I can use default REST API to get some data from server.

Comment: https://api.orthanc-server.com

Comment: There might be some firewall issue while accessing API from your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you said above your app is running inside a docker it couldn't access to localhost unless you run your docker with --network host.

If the app you are trying to access runs also in another docker container you have to ensure that both of them are on the same network and use the internal ip of docker to access it.
You can view it with the command `docker inspect "name_of_container"`  Inside network object in the field IpAdrress

Comment: My app works on docker container but second one (localhost:8042) is a Orthanc server and it isnt on docker container. It is install on my machine and run on localhost:8042 by default

Comment: then if you want to access to the local machine using localhost inside a container you have to run it using --network host  for example   

docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx,   because otherwise you are trying to access to 8042 port inside your container